# Magento Onepage Checkout Doesn't Complete: “Input string was not in a correct format.”

Tags: php, magento

The one page checkout for my store doesn't complete. On the final step (order review), I get this error as a return from the Ajax call to `checkout/onepage/saveOrder`:

```
Server was unable to read request. ---> There is an error in the XML document. ---> Input string was not in a correct format.{"success":true,"error":false}
```

After logging every variable and array I could find in the `saveOrderAction` method of `OnepageController.php`, it looks like the `redirectUrl` from this line is returning nothing:

```
$redirectUrl = $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout()->getRedirectUrl();
```

I haven't found anyone else having this exact problem, and I have a feeling this is being caused by some admin setting that I missed while setting my store up. The production site works fine and I've copied every file onto my local server. Any ideas?

Comment: The checkout process is heavily tied to sessions. Perhaps you might be having issues with configuration differences between production and local environments in regards to your session save settings, or your cookie domains?

Comment: My production environment and local environment both use filesystem session storage, using the exact syntax demonstrated here:

http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/magento-session-storage-which-to-choose-and-why/

Cookie domains are left blank in both environments under System > Config > Web > Session Cookie Management. What do these default to? I haven't found that in my reading yet.

Comment: That sounds fine then..

Comment: I think you're right about it being a session issue. After I get the error response, the cart is empty when I return to the main store view.